# Rails - create object through jQuery validation errors

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been following the tutorial at [this site](http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) to create a jQuery CRUD form.

I have a model `Artist` which has a single validation, to check uniqueness of the `display_name` field.

When POST'ing the create action, the relevant parts of the WEBrick log is showing the following:

```
Started POST "/artists" for 10.1.1.1 at 2012-10-07 13:50:00 +1300
Processing by ArtistsController#create as JS
  Parameters: { (ommited parts for brevity) , "artist"=>{"display_name"=>"Banksy"}, "commit"=> "Create Artist"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Artist Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists`
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Artist Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `artists` WHERE `artists`.`display_name` IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered artists/create.js.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 71ms (Views: 55.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how when it's obvious that in the parameters being passed through, `display_name` is set to a not null string, but in the validation query being run it is checking for an instance where it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the source code for the "POST /artists" controller action?

That **create** action must access the `params` appropriately. In this case, something like:

```
def create
  @artist = Artist.create(params[:artist])
  # then render or redirect
end
```

Is your action calling `Artist.create` with the correct `params`?

Comment: Ah. That did it... I'm using CanCan and was using load_and_authorize_resource in my artists controller, but it doesn't appear that it's loading the resource correctly when called by JS. Will investigate that later, but for now, explicitly creating with params. Thanks